# Как сделать пункт меню "переключателем"?

Tags: java, swing

Пишу меню на Java. Использую стандартный JMenu и JMenuItem. Каким образом можно сделать "залипающие" пункты меню? Т.е. пункт меню, который хранит состояние - выбран/невыбран, - и в случае, если выбран, отображает галочку перед своим названием. По аналогии с ToggleButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, речь идет о [`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html) — стандартном компоненте Swing.
Вот [урок](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), который описывает работу с меню и `JCheckBoxMenuItem` в частности.
И еще один [урок](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJCheckBoxMenuItemEventswithanActionListener.htm) по работе с этим компонентом.